# Automatically apply C# 7 getter and setter style

Tags: c#, coding-style, getter-setter, language-features, c#-7.0

Is there any way to automatically apply C# 7 getter and setter styles (or maybe other new language features)?

It would be nice if there would be any way to automatically change properties like these:

```
public string MyProperty1
{
    get
    {
        return this.myProperty1;
    }
}

public string MyProperty2
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetSomething();
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetSomething(value);
    }
}

public string MyProperty3
{
    get
    {
        return this.myProperty3;
    }
    set
    {
        this.myProperty3 = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChange(nameof(MyProperty3));
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public string MyProperty1 => this.myProperty1;

public string MyProperty2
{
    get => this.GetSomething();
    set => this.SetSomething(value);
}

public string MyProperty3
{
    get => this.myProperty3;
    set
    {
        this.myProperty3 = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChange(nameof(MyProperty3));
    }
}
```

Maybe there is an extension which can handle this task =)

Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you specifically want `MyProperty2` to use a backing field, rather than an auto property?

Comment: @mjwills I have edited my question.

Comment: Can somebody please explain to me why this question got so many down votes? I want to improve my question! =)

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 helps you with that. Such properties show a lightbulb with a "Use expression body for properties" refactoring (IDE0025).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Resharper for this. [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: Not sure why that got a downvote, I use resharper at work and it does this exactly.

Comment: I have given you a downvote as this is not a good answer. Showing us how to do it in R# for example would make it a good answer.

Comment: @gilliduck Thank you sir. This answer helped me =)

Comment: I agree with the downvote. Especially since VS *already* allows a property to change to an exception bodied member. No need for Resharper for this. Resharper can do it for an entire file but that is *NOT* mentioned in this answer. In fact, one wouldn't even know it unless one already used Resharper